# Error is not catching properly

Tags: 8, forms

I have a `try... catch` error handling while saving a custom form in the submit handler, but it is not going to the catch block nor throwing any error to the front end. Instead, it is throwing a fatal error and logging into the Apache error log. How could I force the error to appear on the front end?

```
   public function approve_button_handler(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
          $nid = $form_state->getValue('nid');
          try {
            $terra_node = Node::load($nid);
            $terra_node->set('field_number_of_cpu_s', $number_of_cpus);
            $terra_nodess->set('field_memory', $memory); //this is wrong        
            //as i given $terra_nodess as the loaded entity type node,                                                 
            //or I could give a wrong field name.

            $terra_node->save();
          } catch (Exception $e) { //Not catching here
              drupal_set_message(t($e), 'error');
          } 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that should do thanks. But if something wrong happens in code, how could i know that without looking apache error log?

Comment: IMO don't do that - open terminal, `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`, never close it :)

Comment: thanks, I am currently doing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Drupal question, but a general PHP question. If your site is running PHP7, you can use the new `Throwable` instead of the `Exception`

```
   public function approve_button_handler(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
          $nid = $form_state->getValue('nid');
          try {
            $terra_node = Node::load($nid);
            $terra_node->set('field_number_of_cpu_s', $number_of_cpus);
            $terra_nodess->set('field_memory', $memory); //this is wrong        

            $terra_node->save();
          } catch (Throwable $e) { // Use Throwable instead of Exception here
              drupal_set_message($e->getMessage(), 'error');
          } 
    }
```

Remember, PHP7 only! And I fully agree with Clive's comment, showing Exceptions in the UI is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, I realized that `showing Exceptions in the UI is a bad idea.` What all things fall in exceptions (Not fatal errors) that can show in the front end would be good to know.

Comment: Giving `Throwable` also falls into the `apache error log` not in front end. I have `PHP 7.3.0` running on CentOS-7